# How can you get Gradle to use specific repositories on dynamic versions?

Tags: gradle

We have separate repositories for our dependencies depending on what branch we are working on.  We want to be able to add each of these repositories and have Gradle resolve and stop on the first repository it finds.  We are currently using a + as the version number.  What Gradle currently does (or so it appears) is it finds all the versions in all repositories and finds the latest version (at least when we use a +).

Below is an example of our Gradle scripts.  policy-invoker exists in several repositories; however, we know based on the branch what repository we want for that dependency.  In this case we want the first repository repo1 even though there may be a later version in repo2.  Is there a way to get Gradle to use the version first even on dynamic versions (+) or will we have to use a custom resolution strategy to achieve something like this?

```
apply plugin: 'war'
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'springframework', module: 'spring-binding'
    all*.exclude group: 'springframework', module: 'spring-dao'
    all*.exclude group: 'hsqldb', module: 'hsqldb'
}

dependencies {
    compile "company:policy-invoker:+"      
}
configurations {
    compile.transitive = true
}

war {
    jar.enabled = false
    from 'web'
}
```

Here is a subset of our definition of ordered repos in our main Gradle file.

```
repositories {
        ivy {
            name "repo1"
            url "//network/repo"
            layout "pattern", {
                ivy "[organisation]/[module]/repo1-branch/[revision]/[module]-[revision].xml"
                artifact "[organisation]/[module]/repo1-branch/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]"
            }
        }       
        ivy {
            name "repo2"
            url "//network/repo"
            layout "pattern", {
                ivy "[organisation]/[module]/repo2-branch/[revision]/[module]-[revision].xml"
                artifact "[organisation]/[module]/repo2-branch/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]"
            }
        }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We solved this by creating a Gradle plugin, and mapping branches to Nexus repositories. For example, the develop branch could be mapped to a Snapshots Nexus repository by code in the plugin.

The [aether](http://www.eclipse.org/aether/) library was used to query Nexus. This snippet finds the highest version number.

```
// Create the repository
RemoteRepository.Builder builder = new RemoteRepository.Builder("Snapshots", "default", "http://some.url.to.maven");
RepositoryPolicy policy = new RepositoryPolicy(true, RepositoryPolicy.UPDATE_POLICY_ALWAYS, RepositoryPolicy.CHECKSUM_POLICY_FAIL );
builder.setPolicy(policy);
Repository repository = builder.build();
// artifactName can be a range, like "foo:bar[10.0.+,)"
DefaultArtifact artifact = new DefaultArtifact(artifactName);
VersionRangeRequest request = new VersionRangeRequest();
request.addRepository(repository);
request.setArtifact(artifact);
VersionRangeResult result = MavenResourceHolder.SYSTEM.resolveVersionRange(MavenResourceHolder.SESSION, request);
String versionNumber = null;
if (!result.getVersions().isEmpty()) {
  versionNumber result.getHighestVersion().toString();
}
```

The [jgit](https://eclipse.org/jgit/) library was used to retrieve the Git branch name.

```
FileRepositoryBuilder builder = new FileRepositoryBuilder()
// project is Gradle's Project object
Repository repository = builder.readEnvironment().findGitDir(project.getProjectDir()).build()
String branchName = repository.branch
```